# Zend Framework 1.2 select database runtime after user login

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, frameworks, database-connection

I have this application.ini

```
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = password
resources.db.params.dbname = zend_db
```

but I want choose database after user login: 
for example

login as ADMIN ---> choose mysql db: adminYYY

login as TEST  ---> choose mysql db: TestXXX

login as cat   ---> choose mysql db: catZZZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to instance multiple connections to your server, each one for a different database using Zend_Application_Resource_Multidb. Something like this:

```
resources.multidb.dbadmin.params.host = localhost
resources.multidb.dbadmin.params.username = root
resources.multidb.dbadmin.params.password = password
resources.multidb.dbadmin.params.dbname = 'admin'

resources.multidb.dbtest.params.host = localhost
resources.multidb.dbtest.params.username = root
resources.multidb.dbtest.params.password = password
resources.multidb.dbtest.params.dbname = 'test'

resources.multidb.dbcat.params.host = localhost
resources.multidb.dbcat.params.username = root
resources.multidb.dbcat.params.password = password
resources.multidb.dbcat.params.dbname = 'cat'
```

So you can write a custom auth class that you will use to retrieve each db connection:

```
$resource = $bootstrap->getPluginResource('multidb');
$dbadmin = $resource->getDb('dbadmin');
$dbtest = $resource->getDb('dbtest');
$dbcat = $resource->getDb('dbcat');
```

Or do this trick in your bootstrap.

See [Zend_Application_Resource_Multidb](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.multidb)